# Airflow PythonVirtualOperator throws error with simple example

Tags: python, airflow

I'm trying to create a PythonVirtualOperator and the operator is calling a function just to print out a message.

```
def func(**kwargs):
    print("hello")
```

I defined the operator with the following code:

```
    pv = PythonVirtualenvOperator(
        task_id="pv",
        python_callable=func,
        op_kwargs={"test": "pv"},
        python_version='3.6'
    )
```

Upon triggering the dag, I received error:

```
[2020-05-06 02:03:33,899] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 31244: Subtask ge b'Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "/tmp/venvuv3m91vw/script.py", line 3, in <module>\n    with open(sys.argv[1], "rb") as f: arg_dict = pickle.load(f)\nModuleNotFoundError: No module named \'my_python_virtual_operator_test\'\n'
[2020-05-06 02:03:34,316] {taskinstance.py:1059} ERROR - Command '['/tmp/venvuv3m91vw/bin/python', '/tmp/venvuv3m91vw/script.py', '/tmp/venvuv3m91vw/script.in', '/tmp/venvuv3m91vw/script.out', '/tmp/venvuv3m91vw/string_args.txt']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
Traceback (most recent call last)
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 930, in _run_raw_tas
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/operators/python_operator.py", line 113, in execut
    return_value = self.execute_callable(
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/operators/python_operator.py", line 307, in execute_callabl
    string_args_filename)
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/operators/python_operator.py", line 319, in _execute_in_subproces
    close_fds=True
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 356, in check_outpu
    **kwargs).stdou
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 438, in ru
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/tmp/venvuv3m91vw/bin/python', '/tmp/venvuv3m91vw/script.py', '/tmp/venvuv3m91vw/script.in', '/tmp/venvuv3m91vw/script.out', '/tmp/venvuv3m91vw/string_args.txt']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

The value `my_python_virtual_operator_test` is the folder where my dag is located. It appears the process is unable to find where the dag is located when switched to the virtual environment.

Could anyone advise how to address this, please?

Thanks

Comment: That's exactly what happening. The venv is in another address so you can't reference your local module. I'm trying to figure out how to send a custom module to a PVO with no success so far.

Comment: Try to add to the requeriments parameter the local path to your module. The PVO will execute: pip install [path-to-your-module] so it will be available to your process.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with this issue, we have Airflow 2.7.0 with python3.9 and had to use python2.7. Airflow restricts argument passing from python3 to python2 using kwargs, and I found this in code comment of PythonVirtualenvOperator

> ```
> The function must be defined using def, and not be
> part of a class. All imports must happen inside the function
> and no variables outside of the scope may be referenced. A global scope
> variable named virtualenv_string_args will be available (populated by
> string_args).
> ```

the function that will be executed in virtual environment must be declared with no arguments, and it can only take arguments from global variable as stated above

this works fine:

```
def func():
    passed_argument1=virtualenv_string_args[0]





run_python27_code = PythonVirtualenvOperator(
    task_id='run_python27_code',
    python_callable=check_gearman_status,
    string_args=['passed_argument1','passed_argument2']
    requirements=['gearman'],  # Install gearman package
    python_version='2.7'
    )
```